# Comet with curl or wget

Tags: php, comet

How can I create Wget/curl request to comet server

I have a php based server and embeded linux machine I have to create listener from client side but not based on browser and it must not use sockets.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Consider providing a little more context, and a description of steps you've already taken to attempt to resolve this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are referring to that one facet of Comet where a server-client connection remains open on an unfinished http request for a long(ish) period of time.  I honestly don't think that it would be wise to do that with simple scripting of wget or curl, however it's completely possible to use [libcURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) (the library that cURL is built around) for such a purpose.  Daniel Stenberg, author of cURL and libcURL himself [said so](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.curl.library/31359):

> AFAIK, COMET is just HTTP done in a slightly funny way but still plain HTTP 
>   and libcurl should be able to do it fine. Even if COMET also is a what 
>   wikipedia calls an "umbrella term" which seems to include a lot of different 
>   approaches.

Just one thing (re the socket remark): do realize that "below" whatever solution you'll choose there will be a socket transporting the data, because that's how http gets over the wire.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have 16K users and I can't use socket as the server is not able to support 16K sockets It's a cloud but unfortunately that's I have tried and result is fable.

Comment: Also when I request the server via Curl the result is with 200 code that means It's finished But why the server is giving the curl 200 and for browser pending state?

Comment: @EmilYeritsyan read my last remark again: below a Comet listener there *will* be an open socket as one way or another the traffic needs to be transported, be it over http or websockets.  With your scaling requirements I'm afraid you will need to look for a more conventional technique using shortlived connections.

Comment: @EmilYeritsyan to get a WebSockets conversation going your client has to instruct the server of that intention by sending the appropriate headers ( `Upgrade: WebSocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\n` ).  Without those headers the servers stays in plain http 1.1 mode, hence the 200 response.  But that doesn't change my final remark and I would really encourage you to read a bit more about Comet, it's probably not the silver bullet you expect it to be.